# How to fetch woocomerce orders with vb.net

Tags: vb.net, woocommerce

I'm making a software in vb.net for a client where he needs to fetch orders of particular date from it's wordpress website I'm planning to make a datagrid view to display orders and a button to fetch data from woocommerce get orders api my ui looks like something this

[Image Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4k22W.png)

But the problem is how should I make an api request and it will return me a json data so how to display it properly in datagrid view or is there any thing else or something better to display order or do this thing. Actually I'm not able to find anything like this for sample is there anything available please let me know.

Comment: WooCommerce has a .net library available via nugets.  Maybe start with that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do something like this :-

You will have to use the REST API from woocommerce . . . Go to backend of woocommerce of the site click on woocommerce->settings->advance->rest api

This will get you the globle.key and global.secret.

```
Public Async Sub FillDGV()  'FillDGV
        'any, pending, processing, on-hold, completed, cancelled, refunded, failed and trash
        Dim dic As Dictionary(Of String, String) = New Dictionary(Of String, String)() From {{"status", SrcV}}
        ' Dim dic As Dictionary(Of String, String) = New Dictionary(Of String, String)()From {{"status", "pending"}}
        dic.Add("per_page", "100")
        Dim pageNumber As Integer = 1
        dic.Add("page", pageNumber.ToString())

        Dim rest As RestAPI = New RestAPI(Globle.BaseURL, Globle.Key, Globle.Secret, False)

        Dim wc As WooCommerceNET.WooCommerce.v2.WCObject = New WooCommerceNET.WooCommerce.v2.WCObject(rest)


        Dim orderList As New List(Of WooCommerce.v2.Order)

        orderList = Await wc.Order.GetAll(dic) 'Get All order which status is SrcV

        dgvlist.Rows.Clear()
        For Each item In orderList  'Fill Grid
            Dim Name As String = item.shipping.first_name + " " + item.shipping.last_name + " " + item.billing.phone

            ' CreateFile(item) 'Function call to create text file 

            Dim shippingtotal As String
            Dim shippingmethod As String

            If item.shipping_lines.Count > 0 Then
                shippingtotal = item.shipping_lines.Item(0).total
                shippingmethod = item.shipping_lines.Item(0).method_title
            Else
                shippingtotal = "0.00"
                shippingmethod = ""
            End If

            If item.coupon_lines.Count > 0 Then
                Try

                    dgvlist.Rows.Add(item.number, item.total, Name, item.billing.email, item.shipping.address_1, item.shipping.address_2, item.shipping.city, item.shipping.state, item.shipping.country, item.shipping.postcode, item.shipping.company, shippingmethod, shippingtotal, item.date_created, item.coupon_lines.Item(0).code, item.coupon_lines.Item(0).discount, item.payment_method, item.customer_note, item.total)                    
                Catch ex As Exception
                    'MsgBox(ex.Message)
                End Try
            Else
                Try

                    dgvlist.Rows.Add(item.number, item.total, Name, item.billing.email, item.shipping.address_1, item.shipping.address_2, item.shipping.city, item.shipping.state, item.shipping.country, item.shipping.postcode, item.shipping.company, shippingmethod, shippingtotal, item.date_created, 0, 0, item.payment_method, item.customer_note)

                    ' dgvlist.Rows.Add(item.number, item.total, Name, item.billing.email, item.shipping.address_1, item.shipping.address_2, item.shipping.city, item.shipping.state, item.shipping.country, item.shipping.postcode, item.shipping.company, " ", " ", item.date_created, 0, 0, item.payment_method, item.customer_note)

                Catch ex As Exception
                    'MsgBox(ex.Message)
                End Try
            End If
        Next
    End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply but after installing WooCommerce .net library from nugets when I use your code it gives error RestApi not defiend I added WooCommerceNET before RestApi the error is resolved but after that when I send request it gives error of System.Exception: 'Unknown WooCommerce Restful API version.' please can you help me into this

Comment: Thank you so much it worked I did some problems.

Comment: Hi, is there any way to add loader or something till the api isn't responding so user is not able to click on fetch button again adnd again??

Comment: I would usually hide the fetch button calling the (button.hide) as soon as it's clicked ! !